# What is the easiest way for an end user to update an image slider?

Tags: jquery, content-management-system

I am working currently on a website for a client who knows nothing about web development. I want to include an image slider using jQuery (required), which the client will update periodically depending on his featured stories. How can I do this? Any answer is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the easiest solution here is to use an existing CMS with gallery pluggins. I went with Wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a system that displays the last x images uploaded in your slider. Then you need to build a CMS in which the client can upload new images.